# Loop to change content of href for many anchors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

The content of my posts in Wordpress is a big markup. It is coming from MS Word so it is text wrapped by HTML nested tags and inline styles.

I have a segment of code that is repeated many times in the content (It represents text footnotes). This segment, for the first footnote for example is:

```
<sup><a title="" href="file:///C:/Users/hp/Desktop/file.docx#_ftn1" name="_f
tnref1">
 <span class="MsoFootnoteReference">
  <span dir="LTR">
   <span class="MsoFootnoteReference">
    <span lang="EN-US" style="font-size: 16pt; line-height: 115%;">
     [1]
    </span>
   </span>
  </span>
 </span>
</a></sup>
.....

<a title="" href="file:///C:/Users/hp/Desktop/file.docx#_ftnref1" name="_ftn1">
 <span class="MsoFootnoteReference">
  <span dir="LTR" lang="EN-US" style="font-size: 12.0pt; font-family: 'Simplified Arabic','serif';">
   <span class="MsoFootnoteReference">
    <span lang="EN-US" style="font-size: 12pt; line-height: 115%;">
     [1]
    </span>
   </span>
  </span>
 </span>
</a>
```

My goal is to change the 2 hrefs from:

```
href="file:///C:/Users/hp/Desktop/file.docx#_ftn1" 

href="file:///C:/Users/hp/Desktop/file.docx#_ftnref1"
```

to:

```
href="#_ftn1" 

href="#_ftnref1"
```

so that the user can jump from one anchor to the other.

**Questions:**

1- Is is better to use server side language instead of jquery?

2- How to  loop over the repetitive segments and change the href contents of each couple of anchors?

Thank you very much in advance for your invaluable assistance.

**Solution:**

With the use of Regular expression provided by Broxzier + PHP, the code below is working and can be applied to any data before persisting it on the database.

```
if(preg_match_all('/href\s*=\s*"[^"]+(#[^"]+)"/',get_the_content(),$match))
{
echo preg_replace('/href\s*=\s*"[^"]+(#[^"]+)"/','href="$1"', get_the_content()); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1- Is is better to use server side language instead of jquery?

Neither. The best and fastest option would be to totally remove the website and page name from the link if they're the same as the current page.

One way would be using Regular Expressions, this *could* be done via JavaScript, but I strongly suggest doing this by using a text editor and replace the old data (Wordpress saves revisions anyway).

The following regex will grab the `href` attribute

```
href\s*=\s*"[^"]+(#[^"]+)"
```

Replace this with:

```
href="\1"
```

And you're done.

> 2- How to loop over the repetitive segments and change the href contents of each couple of anchors?

Use a global flag to do this. Since it's content I advice you to do it manually or change the regex so that it will only match the current url.

Please note that this will also replace occurrences in the content, if there is any text like `href="website#flag"` in there. I assumed this was not the case.

--

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: I thank youul for the time to answer and edit. I am trying to learn regular expressions so that I understand your answer fully.

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces You're welcome. I added an image to represent what this regex matches. You can replace the part `none of "` with your site url to make it safer. Any semi-professional text editor will support Regular Expressions, good luck. :)

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces Here you can see the regex in action: http://regex101.com/r/nN8iQ1

Comment: What I really don't understand is the relationship between Editor (like tiny MCE) and regular expressions. I think I need to use PHP + regex to modify content in database.

Comment: Well I opt for the use of PHP+Regex with a goal of changing the whole persisted data in database instead of filtering content whenver there is need to display it. I provided with an edit showing my progress.

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces When you edit a page or post, there is a tab called "Text" in which you can change the HTML. Copy this, change the links, and paste it in again.

Comment: I need that data is persisted in database without such hrefs. Can you  tell me what is the regex pattern  of the replacement( `href="\1"` doesnt work unfortunately) so that I use `preg_replace` correctly just before `wp_insert_post()`. Thank you.

Comment: Ok thank you, I found it. the replacement is `href="$1"` instead of `href="\1"`. Preg_replace resolved my issue, now all posts will not have the ugly hrefs when inserted. Fortunately database is still empty. :-) Good luck sir

Answer (score 1):

Using `jQuery.attr()` and `hash` property of `<a>`

```
$('a').has('.MsoFootnoteReference').attr('href',function( idx,oldHref){
   return this.hash;
});
```

You might want to use some html cleaning on your WYSIWYG html submissions that will clean out unwanted classes and modify the href's for you.

For example `SimpleHtmlDOM` php library uses css type selectors to modify html and you could use it to modify any `href` with `file://` in it for example

Comment: Thank you very much.Should I understand that it is better to use client side for this operation? And how to to tell jquery to remove all characters before `#_ftn` in href?

Comment: If you understand jQuery liek selectors and DOM traversing...that library has low learning curve. Also...some WYSIWYG like CKEditor have some `paste from word` ability to clean stuff up

Comment: I see, unfortunately, under the  CMS I am using (Wordpress), there is TinyMCE, which I think doesnt cotain the feature.

Comment: the jQuery method will get you up and running quickly

Comment: Okey, It looks like the jquery approach is the fast one for me. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: You shouldn't change PHP code of CMS systems like Wordpress, use/write plugins intead. If Wordpress launches an update and you decide to install it, your changes will be lost.

Comment: I totally agree with you @Broxzier. Modifiying CMS code means use of plugins or functions.php (if one theme concerned).

Comment: @Broxzier modifying a CMS doesn't mean not using best practices by hooking into it...if indeed it is developed with hooks in mind...not all are. The point wasn't about how to modify a CMS...rather about `you're not locked in`

Comment: @charlietfl WordPress is developed with a few hooks. From your comment I understood modifying the actual code instead.

Comment: @Broxzier well that was a complete assumption on your part...isn't plugging into wordpress modifying it's core functionality/

Comment: @charlietfl "_a CMS is just php code... and can always be modified_" basically sais the same.

Comment: @Broxzier you're getting stuck on semantics...modifying does not implicitley suggest changing core